# Comparing with List Patterns

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

First consider the following code, which counts the number of blank spaces in a string:

```
countSpaces :: String -> Int
countSpaces [] = 0
countSpaces (c : restOfString)
    = d + countSpaces restOfString
       where d = if c == ’ ’ then 1
                             else 0
```

Here is my questions:

1, if I make a call: `countSpaces "abc"` , then what happens when this function tries to match the string `"abc"` with `(c: restOfString)`. I mean, `restOfString` is: `"abc"` in this call but what is `(c:restOfString)` ? you are 'consing' something(the variable? `c` ) to `restOfstring`  and then you are trying to match? I just don't get it.

2, I try to run the code but I am getting a parse error why?

> parse error on input ‘´’

3,will this function  call `countSpaces`  to infinity? since `restOfString` is always the same and not reduced, eg. making the call `countSpaces "aaa"` will not change after the first call,second  or any call, right?

- Added afterwards*

Now consider this code which completes the same task:

```
countSpaces :: String -> Int
countSpaces [] = 0
countSpaces (’ ’ : restOfString)
        = 1 + countSpaces restOfString
countSpaces (_ : restOfString)
        = 0 + countSpaces restOfString
```

1, so if we try to make a call  `countSpaces  "abc"` the pattern `(’ ’ : restOfString)` will just get bigger since every time `countSpaces` gets called this will just cons a `' '` to `restOfString`, Unless every time `countSpaces` will get called  the first char in the string will be changed to: `'  '` . so in the first call of `countSpaces "abc"`  then `(’ ’ : restOfString)` is `' ':"bc"` ,  which is confusing right, since it replaced `"a"` with a blank instead of consing it so that we get: `" abc"`

Comment: `"abc"` is just syntactic sugar for `['a', 'b', 'c']` or `'a':'b':'c':[]`.

Comment: You're using weird apostrophes. Compare this: `'` to yours, `’`. They're different characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> 1, if I make a call: countSpaces "abc" , then what happens when this function tries to match the string "abc" with: (c: restOfString).

When you match that pattern using the cons operator `:`, the element on the left of `:` is the first element in the list, and on the right of `:` is the remainder of the list. The following are equivalent:

```haskell
"abc" == 'a' : "bc"
```

Since a `String` is a list of characters (specifically, `[Char]`), the above could also be written as:

```haskell
"abc" == 'a' : 'b' : 'c' : []
```

> 2, I try to run the code but I am getting a parse error why?

Your parse error is because you are using the wrong character for a single quote. You are using [unicode 0x2019](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2019/index.htm) when you should be using the [ASCII/Unicode Apostrophe character: `'`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/27/index.htm)

> 3,will this function call countSpaces to infinity?

It will only count to infinity if your string is infinite. The reduction actually happens in this part:

```haskell
 countSpaces restOfString
```

To understand why, see my answer for part 1. In the case of "abc", `restOfString` is "bc".

> 4, so if we try to make a call countSpaces "abc" the pattern: (’ ’ : restOfString) will just get bigger since everytime countSpaces gets called this will just cons a ' ' to restOfString, Unless every time countSpaces will get called then the first char in the string will be changed to: ' ' . so in the first call of countSpaces "abc" then (’ ’ : restOfString) is ' ':"bc" , which is confusing right?

I think your confusion originates from the fact that pattern matching and building a list look identical. i.e. what happens when you write `(' ':restOfString)` depends entirely on context.

You can think of a function definition as being broken up into two parts separated by the `=` sign:

```haskell
countSpaces (' ' : restOfString)   =   1 + countSpaces restOfString
^                              ^   ^   ^                          ^
|                              |   |   |                          |
--------------------------------   |   ----------------------------
               |                   |                 |
        Pattern Matching       Separator       Function Body
```

The Pattern Matching portion does not affect the output. When you use `(' ' : restOfString)` on the Pattern Matching side, you are saying, "If the parameter passed into the `countSpaces` function starts with a space, then return what is in this function body. If the first character is not a space, then try the next pattern defined". In either case (whether it is matched or not), the value passed into `countSpaces` is not modified in any way (it does not have a space put in front of it; that kind of thing only happens in the function body).

Conversely, when you put `(' ' : restOfString)` in the Function Body, you are saying "return the `restOfString` value prefixed with a space character".

Comment: Ok, here is what confuses me:  if we were to change: c  to 'c' would that imply that you would change the first element in restOfList to 'c' ?  but ('c':"ab") would produce "cab". The result differs if it is a parameter(as in this function) or a string(that is not a parameter to a call) @Chad Gilberg

Comment: `('c':"ab")` in the context of pattern matching will *only* ever match the string "cab". If you are instead _returning_ `('c':"ab")`, then you are returning the string "cab". Remember that `c` is a variable name and `'c'` is a `Char` because it is surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: `countSpaces (' ' : restOfString) = 1 + countSpaces restOfString` and 
`countSpaces (_ : restOfString) = 0 + countSpaces restOfString` are valid ways of solving the problem through pattern matching.

Comment: sorry for asking so many question, I just want to understand , hope you could bear with me :) . I changed(added) in the main question above, maybe u could take a look :) @Chad Gillberg

Comment: I've added a response to my answer that should hopefully shed a bit more light on the difference between pattern matching and function bodies.

Comment: Another way of thinking about the pattern is that it is a function call that could *produce* the argument, not a call that takes the argument as input.